# New TLDs and Their Impact on SEO

Tags: seo, top-level-domains

With a whole slew of new TLDs becoming available how will they affect SEO?

While I realize some of these domains are fairly general, such as `.ninja` others are very specific such as `.dental` and this leaves me curious as to how this new TLDs will ultimately affect SEO?